# If X and Y are binary random variables, does E[XY] = P{X = 1, Y = 1}, and if so, why?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have been told that if X and Y are binary/indicator random variables, then E[XY] = P{X = 1, Y = 1}. However, I cannot understand why this is the case; if indeed it is correct. Is it correct, and if so, why? i.e., how is it proved?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For discrete random variables we have $E[h(X,Y)] = \sum_{(x,y)}h(x,y)P[(X,Y)=(x,y)]$. Here the sum is over all (finite or countably infinite) values of $(x,y)$ that $(X,Y)$ can take.  Alternatively, define $Z=XY$ and find the probability mass function for $Z$.

Comment: Note that $XY = 1$ iff $X=1$ and $Y=1$. So $XY = 1$ with probability $P(X=1, Y =1)$ and is $0$ otherwise i.e. $XY$ is also a binary random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition, noticing that the possible values for $(X,Y)$ are $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$:
$$E(XY)=0\cdot 0\cdot P(X=0,Y=0)+ 1\cdot 0 \cdot P(X=1,Y=0)+\\+0\cdot 1 \cdot P(X=0,Y=1)+ 1\cdot 1 \cdot P(X=1,Y=1)$$
$$E(XY)=P(X=1,Y=1)$$

The zeros and ones do the trick.

Comment: This is very clear; thank you very much! :)